# jQuery - Dragable sortable lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to create sortable lists with labels that are also dragable. I mean, I can do sortable lists, but I would like them to also be dragable, so it is posible to change their place as I see it ( eg. move some from the middle to the front etc ). I did put one list within another but that was big misundarstanding. Ive looked thru the demos and was thinking about mixing ( including ) sortable lists with ( into ) portlets. Do you guys know of any better solution on how to get this done ?

Answer (score 0):

You can user jQuery UI library to add dragable and sortable to list

[jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default)

you can add content and update the style as you want ...